# JQUERY value of option to be stored in a variable

Tags: jquery

I am trying to store value into `var`(variable) using JQuery, but its giving me attributes value. Actually, I dont want to store attribute/elements/tags value.

Let me give you exact what i want by example,

Below code is my `HTML` code:

```js
$('#subcategorytwo').on('click', function(event) {
        //  var categorytwo = value;
        //console.log((this.value, text.(this.value));
    
     var opt = $("#subcategorytwo").text(event.target.value)

   $("select").append('<option value="' + opt+ '">' + opt +'</option>')
   
     $('#fetchvalue').val(event.target.value);


    });
```

```html
<ul name="subcategorytwo" id="subcategorytwo" style="list-style: none;">
  <li value="1">ROlce royce</li>
  <li value="2">Mercedese</li>
</ul>

// note actually i want to store in y variable ROlce royce
```

You can see in my `HTML code` as `<li value="2">Mercedese</li>`, **actually i want to store `MERCEDESE` in my variable** but, not want to store value attribute as 2)

Comment: What exactly is a `<ui>` element?  I do not see it listed in the https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#elements-3  Did you typo `<ul>` ?

Comment: yes its `<ul>` tag and i have corrected code. but did you read it what actually i want? @Taplar

Comment: `$("#subcategorytwo").text(event.target.value)` is going to replace the entire contents of the `ul` with whatever the target value is.  Is that desired?

Comment: Also there is no `<select>` in your snipplet, nor element with an id of `fetchvalue` to explain what those lines are doing.

Comment: Use **.text** or **.html()** http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: I actually i am asking `jquery` how to store... but i dont wan to use `select`

Comment: Please clarify your question.  It's unclear what your end goal is with the logic you've provided.

Comment: My question is really simple, ` <li value="2">Mercedese</li>` how to store in jquery **Mercedese** in `var`? @Taplar

Answer (score 0):

You actually cannot use the .text() function with #subcategorytwo because #subcategorytwo is a ul and it doesn't store any text values.

You have to use the text() function against one of the li items instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to grab the text of the li that has a value of 2 then that would be something like...

```js
var car = $('#subcategorytwo li[value="2"]').text();

console.log(car);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul name="subcategorytwo" id="subcategorytwo" style="list-style: none;">
  <li value="1">ROlce royce</li>
  <li value="2">Mercedese</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello its work...thank you so much....but I have category>subcategory>subcategotytwo this type of structure...how can i show 3value in one place?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question.  Your html uses an id, which cannot be repeated, so the nesting structure for this logic isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

to get the element text use `.textContent` or jQuery `.text()`

```js
console.log('click the li');
$('#subcategorytwo').on('click', function(event) {
  var opt = $(event.target).text();
  // or
  //var opt = event.target.textContent;
  console.log(opt)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul name="subcategorytwo" id="subcategorytwo" style="list-style: none;">
  <li value="1">ROlce royce</li>
  <li value="2">Mercedese</li>
</ul>
```